# How do I restore shortcut icon images in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons, shortcuts

I recently uninstalled UI tweaking software WinBubble. This offered the option to remove the shortcut arrow from shortcuts (Similar to TweakUI for XP). Since uninstalling, all of my shortcuts look like the icon is still there, but overlaid on top of it is the standard "no association" icon (shown), which is really annoying. Anyone know how to solve this without a reinstall?

**EDIT:** I'm not actually looking to restore the arrow. I actually prefer not having it there. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the incorrect icon overlaid over the correct ones, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have the shortcut arrow back in regedit go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons
```

and look for the key 29 and delete it.

[image: Regedit key 29]

Otherwise you can change it to an icon on your system that you like. And there are many more options of what to do [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaappearance/thread/4e79e420-ae0d-453b-9bf7-280780fed68d).

Comment: Such a nice day for you steve! Giving many good answers!

Comment: This actually did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Woo! Googled up my problem with "Windows 7" shortcut icons and found this thread, which has fixed everything.

First, I looked under this key,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons
```

Then by backing up then deleting the following, I fixed the problem;

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"29"="C:\\Program Files\\Desktop Icon Toy\\Empty.ico"
```

Note that the problem didn't happen immediately after uninstalling Desktop Toy, cause I uninstalled that a few months back... very strange! All good now.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search has turned up [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3606-shortcut-arrow-change-remove-restore.html), but I've not directly tried this myself (I can confirm the reg keys below match my system, which has not been modified with regards to shortcut arrows).

The registry section at the top has a "remove shortcut icon" bit, which is primarily a registry reset. I've had a quick nose in the `.reg` file and essentially they are setting the following keys:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\piffile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSHFile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"29"=-
```

If registry editing is not your thing, follow the link and try to slightly more automated instructions there.